# SonataAdminBundle number input

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

Hello everyone I'm trying to add number input to sonata edit/create page but I have an error. Here are my files: 
Product.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
 */
private $price;
```

ProductAdmin.php

```
$formMapper
    ->with('Content', ['class' => 'col-md-9'])            
        ->add('price', NumberType::class)
```

When I submit my form I get this:

```
Expected argument of type "double", "double" given
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
```

I tried fill with `12.00 12,00 12` but I'm getting this error all the time. Where is the problem I don't have any idea. I'm new in symfony and sonata.